# Unable to Clone Gitflow

Tags: git-flow

I've been unable to clone Gitflow.

I've used:  **git clone --recursive https://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git** 
to no avail.

This is the same for both https and ssh. 
I do have a valid ssh key and have been using it without issue on other repos.

It seems to have a problem with the recursive modules. This is the log from the bash:
[image]

I've even run the command from a prompt with elevated privileges, to no avail.

Any idea how to get that cloning complete?

Comment: This doesn't help you, but I just tried the same command on my machine, and it worked without any issues.  Can I ask what version of git you are using?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I am using version 2.20.1 on Windows. Weird how it is only the Submodules which seem to be giving me grief. I'm also in a work environment, so group policy is coming into play. Perhaps a proxy issue? I'll try this at home this evening to see what happens.

Comment: I can confirm that I was also using 2.20.1 on Windows, and this worked for me, so, yes, perhaps something in your environment getting in the way.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Yeah, I tried it at home and it cloned without a problem. In any case, the team here uses Sourcetree and the Gitflow stuff in that product works. So, there's no compelling reason to continue here on a fool's errand. Thanks for your help.